# What options are there in flutterflow for configuring the Android system navbar?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-android

I've downloaded my APK from flutterflow, but can see this (opaque) navbar at the bottom (native Android feature):

[image]

I've noticed on other apps that I have on my phone that this bar is set to transparent (probably, more like translucent).

Are there any options in flutterflow around this? There doesn't appear to be anything in the docs and it's not obvious from the flutterflow UI.